# Is the patch 'Ensure get_futex_key_refs() always implies a barrier' backported to 3.2.0 precise?

Tags: kernel, patch

I got an error on a process on a server with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and Linux 3.2.0-101 kernel that seems to be linked to futex.

The strace is:

```
futex(0x25436a4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1897, {8720249, 429576138}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x2543718, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8720249, 430115772}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8720249, 430246316}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8720249, 430343247}) = 0
futex(0x25436a4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1899, {8720249, 930343247}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x2543718, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8720249, 930688684}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8720249, 930799335}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8720249, 930887869}) = 0
futex(0x25436a4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1901, {8720250, 430887869}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x2543718, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

A fix has been found, and can be seen here https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/76835b0ebf8a7fe85beb03c75121419a7dec52f0

I can't find if this patch has been backported on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and Linux 3.2.0-xxx kernel.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have kernel v3.2.x you don't have Ubuntu 12.04.2. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support#A12.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support. Also, Ubuntu 12.04.2 has been superseded and doesn't receive any more support or upgrades since 08/2014. For the same reason it's off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

First, 12.04.2 is EOL, and probably shouldn't be supported.

However, this might help (and it is generic): Read the changelogs.

```
apt-get changelog linux-image-$(uname -r)
apt-get changelog linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```